# Asp.net ajax combobox doesn't display correctly when inserted inside a tab control

Tags: asp.net, ajax, combobox, tabcontrol

I have a display problem when I try to use a ajax combobox inside a tab control:
when my tab control loads on the page where the combobox is, everything works fine; however, if it loads on a another page, the you change to the page which contains the combobox, the right button (which opens the list of the combobox) isn't displayed at all.

Has someone been through this behavior? And maybe found a solution ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Firebug in FireFox (this tool is very good if you dont use it) and right-click the area where your drop arrow should be, then select "Inspect Element".  At the bottom of your browser screen, you will see a couple windows.  One window will detail teh styles being applied to the arrow area.

Look for a style that is making visibility of either a <td> or <img> to be hidden.  The Ajax ComboBox control, sadly, is laid out in a table.

Comment: Hi Cen,
I already tried that before, but the problem is that it seems that the style is not rendered correctly.  Currently I'm able to bypass the problem using a javascript function that resets the width, height and visibility style of the combobox when switching tabs, but I'm not really happy with this solution...

Comment: What I ended up doing for myself was actually editing out all of the styling from the control itself and recompiling.  It's much easier to work with.